# Trying to create a chrome extension on chrome OS operating system

Tags: html, json

So here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "name":"My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test Description",
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_title": "Title of Extenstion",
    "default_popup": "mypopup.html"
  },
  "permissions":
  [
   "activeTab",
   "notifications",
   "create",
   "tabs"
  ]
}
```

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a test popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am very new to this and tried following a tutorial, i followed it step by step, both the manifest and html document are in the same folder. It shows my extension in the extensions tab and everything, but when i click on it nothing happens like it should. Can anyone find what i did wrong because my editor says nothing is wrong. All i want to do is display a simple popup in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that it shows a popup, but it is a very small square because everything is correct but you didn't put this:

**style.css**

```
body, html {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**mypopup.html in the head:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

If that doesn't work, then you have the wrong file name/location. Also you should right click the browser_action icon and click "inspect popup" to see the dev tools to debug it.

Comment: Nothing was showing up at all, but using this now it is showing a very small box

Comment: Well 100px will be small but if it is not working it would be less than that (like 10px). 100px isn't the small I was talking about. Just change the 100px to something bigger or anything you want it to be. So it is working now for you.

Comment: ah i found the issue, i had the title to the html wrong so it was referencing a file from another of my projects

Comment: i did not think about the inspect popup button, thank you

Comment: If you are talking about the tab title (<title>) or default_title, then it shouldn't matter. The file name is what matters.

Comment: i had the file name spelled wrong, that was what the problem was, thank you

Comment: That is what I thought at first but I assumed you had it correct. So I purposely put the file names in bold instead if the language.